# How can I get string value of selector?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I mean when we initialize Selector like this:

```
let stringLocator = 'some element locator'
selector = new Selector(stringLocator)
```

is that possible to get original string locator somehow like this:

```
selector.locator
```

p.s. This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510808/how-to-override-standard-testcafe-errors) where I've found some hacky workarounds to get testcafe display my xpath locators in error.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution, but testcafe provides on option to define your own custom methods to a selector https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/addcustommethods.html perhaps this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testcafe does not support this, but you can use the following approach

```
function createSelector (locator) {
  return Object.assign(Selector(locator), { locator });
}

const selector = createSelector('#button');

console.log(selector.locator)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue yesterday. The apiFnChain contains the fnChain you used for the selector. It is behind a symbol. This is what helped me. Maybe this will help you too.

```js
const selector = Selector('button.explore-button').withText('Explore the site')
const selectorFnChain = selector[Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(selector)[0]].options.apiFnChain
console.log(selectorFnChain)
```

This will give you this:

```
Selector('button.explore-button'),.withText('Explore the site')
```

You don't have to get the entire chain but this was the most helpful for me.

Comment: Yes, I've used that to monkey patch testcafe to log XpathSelectors
https://github.com/Vla8islav/testcafe/commit/d6e2a7f4ae79ffaef164df30e51f56480d569e6a

Comment: I love that line: "Unable to collect xpath locator, this is hardcode, so fix that" :D